# Is torsion the geometrical description of the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, string-theory

The low-energy effective action of the bosonic string is given by:
$$S=\frac{1}{2k_0^2}\int d^{26}x\sqrt{-g}e^{-2\Phi}({\cal R}+4\partial_\mu\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi-\frac{1}{12}H_{\mu\nu\rho}H^{\mu\nu\rho}),$$
where $k_0^2\sim l_s^{24}$, $\cal R$ is the scalar curvature, $\Phi$ is the dilaton field and
$$H_{\mu\nu\rho}=\partial_\mu B_{\nu\rho}+\partial_\nu B_{\rho\mu}+\partial_\rho B_{\mu\nu},$$
where $B_{\mu\nu}$ is the Kalb-Ramond field.

David Tong says in his [String Theory Notes (7.2.1)](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/string7.pdf) that the term $H_{\mu\nu\rho}H^{\mu\nu\rho}$ plays the same role as torsion in general relativity providing an anti-symmetric component to the affine connection. I take this to mean that an objects' angular momentum vector rotates as it moves along a geodesic. Now a magnetic field makes the spin of a charged particle precess ([Larmor Precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession)). Does this mean that the Kalb-Ramond field is related to an ordinary magnetic field in 4D spacetime?

Comment: I do not understand why the K-R field strength being like a spacetime torsion would imply it being like a magnetic field. A magnetic field rotates angular momenta of *charged* particles proportional to their charge, while spacetime torsion acts on *all* worldlines regardless of charge and doesn't rotate angular momenta but more "local reference frames". These two things are entirely dissimilar except that they both involve the word "rotate".

Comment: Apparently there is a classical theory of gravitation called the Einstein-Cartan theory in which torsion and spin are related by equations.

Comment: The spin tensor/spin connection is a more general notion than just "spin" (again, just because two things involve the same word that doesn't mean they are the same)  and this still doesn't establish any link to charge.

Answer (score 1):

Einstein's [unified field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_unified_field_theories#Einstein%27s_geometric_approaches) attempted to unify gravity and electromagnetism. In its more modern formulation the torsion vector (contracted torsion tensor $T^k{}_{ik}$) is identified with the 4-potential of EM field. See e.g. [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00766412) for details.